# How do I check if my address node exists and if it has a string value in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to check if an element exist and if it has a string value.

```
<AddressName>My address</AddressName>
```

In vb should I do it this way?

```
If Not AddressNameNode is nothing Then
```

My vb code will check if it exists. How do I also check if it has a string value?

Comment: Are you using XmlNodes or XElements.  What is AddressNameNode?  Have you already called something to look up the node and AddressNameNode is the result of that lookup?

Comment: Is `AddressNameNode` a `XElement` object? Please show the code that reads the XML element into AddressNameNode.

Comment: AddressName is a xml element

Comment: The value of the node will always be a String.  You could test String.IsNullOrEmpty() to see if it's a blank string.  Even if it's a number, it's a string representation of that number.

Comment: Okay thank you dwilliss

Comment: The type can't be `xml element`. You can't have a space in the type name. There are several sets of types used to encapsulate xml elements, I'm trying to find out which one you are using.

Comment: Oh I see. I want to check if this element named AddressName exist in the xml document. I also want to check if it has a string in it which I think I can say string.length > 0.

Comment: Is `AddressNameNode` an object of type [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`System.Xml.Linq.XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)?  How is it initialized?  Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing sample XML being read in and the `AddressNameNode` initialized?